# How do I say "once a week" vs. "twice (or more) a week"?

Tags: word-order, time

I want to answer the question “Wie oft räumen Sie Ihr Zimmer auf?”, saying that I clean my room once a week.

I know that I have to put *auf* at the end of my answer (because it is a separable verb) and thus if I just want to say that I clean my room, I would say:

> Ich räume mein Zimmer auf.

But how do I add *once a week* or *twice a week* or something like that?

I searched the phrase *once a week,* and I think it is *wöchentlich.*

So will it be valid to say the following?

> Ich räume wöchentlich mein Zimmer auf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Ich räume wöchentlich mein Zimmer auf.

This is correct. Starting from here, there are several options to indicate other intervals:

**n-wöchentlich**

You *could* say *zweiwöchentlich*, *dreiwöchentlich* etc., which means that you perform the activity once every n weeks. However, these words sound quite formal and are mostly used in written announcements such as "Die Zeitschrift erscheint zweiwöchentlich.", "Die Veranstaltung findet dreiwöchentlich statt."

The same works with other intervals, as well:

- *zweimonatlich* means once every two months
- *zweijährlich* means once every two years
  etc.

**n-mal pro Woche; alle n Wochen**

This expression can be used in all contexts and is also somewhat more flexible than the above one:

- If the frequency of the described event is higher than the reference interval (e.g. a week), you can say *dreimal pro Woche* (three times every week).
- If the frequency of the described event is lower than the reference interval, you can say *[einmal] alle drei Wochen* ([once] every three weeks).
- Lastly, you can also express other intervals like this, e.g. *fünfmal alle zwei Wochen* (five times every two weeks).

Comment: Placing the expression just before *auf* is also correct: *Ich räume mein Zimmer wöchentlich auf* / *Ich räume mein Zimmer zweimal pro Woche auf*.  This order emphasises the temporal information you want to convey, especially if you are responding to the question *Wie oft...?*

Comment: _zweimal wöchentlich_ also works instead of _zweimal pro Woche_ or _zweimal in der Woche_. To keep in mind: _eine zweiwöch**ig**e Veranstaltung_ is an event that lasts for 2 weeks, whereas _eine zweiwöch**entlich**e Veranstaltung_ takes place every other week.

Comment: @Crissov: True. *dreimal zweiwöchentlich*, on the other hand, seems to sound strangely weird and less comprehensible than *dreimal alle zwei Wochen*.

Comment: And then there’s also *n*-mal die Woche, although I’m not sure how colloquial it actually is.